# Выводит результат одной строкой PHP query

Tags: php, phpquery

Хочу вывести все содержимое ссылок по отдельности, а он соединяет и выводит одной большой строкой.

```
require_once 'phpQuery/phpQuery/phpQuery.php';

$html = file_get_contents('http://site.site.ru/avtomagaziny/');
phpQuery::newDocument( $html );

$title = pq( '.list-item h3 a' )->html(); 
echo $title;

phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
```

результат: ссылка1ссылка2ссылка3

желаемый результат вывести все циклом что бы я мог записать каждую итерацию в базу данных

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
require 'phpQuery/phpQuery.php';

$html = file_get_contents('https://odessa1.com/catalog/avtomagaziny/');
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
$entry = $document->find('.event');

foreach ($entry as $el) {
    $pq = pq($el);
    echo $pq->find('.main_event_block > a')->attr('href') . "\r\n";
}

phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
```

Вывод получается такой

```
//https://odessa1.com/catalog/autocentre-ooo-auto-group.html
//https://odessa1.com/catalog/autocentre-hyundai-bazis-auto.html
//https://odessa1.com/catalog/service-centre-skoda.html
//etc...
```